# GitHub API throws error when I don't make any GitHub API calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, github-api

I have a website written with AngularJS that I have wrapped in end-to-end tests with Protractor. On this site, I have several links to GitHub repositories for said website.  I have several end-to-end tests that click those links and verify that they take you to the correct page.  I also have assertions at the end of each test that verifies that no javascript errors were thrown.

Occasionally, when the tests run, I see the following error in the test results:

```
<failure type="toBe" message="Expected 'https://github.com/DnDGen/CharacterGen 0:0 Fetch API cannot load https://api.github.com/_private/browser/stats. ' to be ''."><![CDATA[Error: Failed expectation
    at app.assertNoErrors (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\Tests\Integration\Views\commonTestFunctions.js:17:47)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\Cid the Coatrack\Documents\Programming\Projects\DNDGenSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)]]>
</failure>
```

This is particularly confusing because I am making no API calls to GitHub at all - I merely place hyperlinks on the page for the user to click:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="collapsedGithubLinks" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">GitHub <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a id="githubOrganizationLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen">The DnDGen Project</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a id="githubDiceLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen/RollGen">RollGen</a></li>
            <li><a id="githubEquipmentLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen/TreasureGen">TreasureGen</a></li>
            <li><a id="githubCharacterLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen/CharacterGen">CharacterGen</a></li>
            <li><a id="githubEncounterLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen/EncounterGen">EncounterGen</a></li>
            <li><a id="githubDungeonLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen/DungeonGen">DungeonGen</a></li>
            <li><a id="githubSiteLink" href="https://github.com/DnDGen/DNDGenSite">This Site</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="padding-right"><a id="officialDndLink" href="http://dnd.wizards.com/">Official D&D Site</a></li>
</ul>
```

What is even stranger is that the test that fails is not consistent.  Sometimes, all tests will pass.  Other times, several tests will fail.  And the tests that fail are not related to those links - sometimes tests asserting that the brand is shown in the navbar, with no relation or reference to the links at all, will fail for the same API reason.

I have yet to see this error ever occur on [the live site](http://dndgen.com).  I want to know what is causing this to sporadically occur and how I can fix it.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code that I am using to assert that there are no errors:

```
function assertNoErrors(browserLog) {
    for (var i = 0; i < browserLog.length; i++)
        expect(browserLog[i].message).toBe('');

    expect(browserLog.length).toBe(0);
}
```

This is called this way:

```
afterEach(function () {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(assertNoErrors);
});
```

**Update 2:**

I should also clarify that any test that navigates outside of my site (i.e., tests that click the GitHub links) do not check for errors, because I did not want tests to fail because of errors on pages that I do not write and control.  The tests that do fail stay purely internal to my web app, and almost never interact with the github links at all.

Here is an example of one of the tests that fails randomly (it is not always this one, nor does this one fail all the time)

```
it('shows the brand', function () {
    expect(element(by.css('.navbar-brand')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

For the reference, this is the HTML for that object

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="~/">DnDGen</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder if it's possible that your test suite is loading enough pages fast enough all from one IP address that it might be running into some sort of rate limiting?  The pages themselves may be using the API.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to assert there are no errors?

Comment: Certainly.  I will add it as an edit to the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - it is an idea, but the fact that tests fail that do not interact with the links at all, and because of the same API issue, would seem to rule that out.

Comment: You said you click the github links and verify no errors.  That will load github pages.

Comment: I may have mis-described.  I run the verification after all tests that remain internal to my site.  I do not check for errors on tests that lead to external sites such as GitHub.  See Update 2.  The problem is that these internal tests still fail because of the API error, even though they make no API call and do not interact with a GitHub page.

Comment: Somewhere, you are operating under a false assumption that no GitHub API calls are made. Unless some code is purposely masquerading and deceptively creating a Github looking error, then some Github code is executing somewhere.  You could use either the network tab in a browser or a network analyzer like WireShark to see exactly what Github API calls are being made and that might give you a hint of where to look for them.

Comment: Is it possible that the tests that open github pages generate the errors in console and when your internal site tests are run the errors from the previous tests remain in the console?

Comment: @finspin - a good idea. I will double-check, but I reload the page before every test (to ensure a fresh environment), so lingering issues shouldn't occur - unless the API call is not done when I refresh, and navigating off the GitHub page breaks the API call. I will investigate this further

Comment: @finspin - there is a chance that a previous test is messing with later tests - the tests that are most likely to fail come closely after the tests that navigate outside the site.  I'm not entirely sure what to do about this, but that is the most promising root cause I have seen yet.

Comment: @cidthecoatrack I would suggest running the suite with `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true` setting and see if your results get more stable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an educated guess, but if you are clicking the links and navigating to github, and your own code does not make a call to `https://api.github.com/_private/browser/stats`, these errors are probably from a github page and not your own.

I don't have an elegant solution for filtering these out off the top of my head unfortunately. You could not assert there are no errors in the console on tests that interact with third party sites.

Comment: I actually make sure to NOT check for errors on any test that navigates to a page outside my site - specifically in case they have errors I cannot control.  But a good thought, yes.

Comment: Interesting, so you do not check for errors in tests that click the links but you still get your error checking assertions thrown?

Comment: Correct.  Different tests - tests that do not interact with the links or with the GitHub sites - fail because of the GitHub API error.  Quite baffling indeed.

Comment: Sounds like something happening in the background then. I'm not sure if you are using a browser that supports fetch natively, but perhaps it is attempting to fetch that url and failing when you navigate away in another unrelated test. Can you reproduce in isolation?

Comment: I cannot reproduce consistently.  Sometimes tests fail, sometimes all pass.    As for isolation, I have not run individual tests (not the easiest thing to do with Grunt and Protractor).  The inconsistent nature of the problem makes it all the harder to isolate, because a test that fails one run may never exhibit the bug again, even in groups.  Also, the browsers I am running with Protractor are Chrome and Firefox.